# Having trouble fetching my posts from medium

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

Can't seem to be able to render my article from medium on my website, I tried different apis like this  `https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@khaledb.yahya` and adding bearer and acces tokens to headers or this `GET https://api.medium.com/v1/users/{{userId}}/publications` and different methods but still no luck. I keep getting these error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 () settle.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError`

code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Blog = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.medium.com/v1/users/{@khaledb.yahya}/publications`)
      .then((res) => {
        setPosts(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div name="blog" className="w-full md:h-screen text-gray-300">
      <div className="max-w-[1000px] mx-auto p-4 flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full">
        <div className="pb-8">
          <p className="text-4xl font-bold inline border-b-4 border-blue-600">
            Blog
          </p>
          <p className="py-6">// Check out some of my recent articles</p>
        </div>

        {/* container for projects */}
        <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
          {/* Gird Item */}
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <div
              key={post.id}
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.image})` }}
              className="shadow-lg shadow-[#040c16] group container rounded-md
              flex justify-center text-center items-center mx-auto content-div "
            >
              {/* Hover effect for images */}
              <div className="opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 ">
                <span className="text-2xl font bold text-white tracking-wider ">
                  {post.title}
                </span>
                <div className="pt-8 text-center ">
                  <p>{post.description}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

Comment: First of all, you should remove `{}` from the url. Second, I don't see a part where you pass access token to the request

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPosts() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://api.medium.com/v1/users/@khaledb.yahya/publications",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization:
              "Bearer 2bc9dfab8e546b89ff23736716b2f279c2229afc84a464d468126ff021b9654c0",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      setPosts(json.data);
    }
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
@Konrad